# Targetting XML with namespace using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm new to XML and I'm having a hard time grabbing the MarketRent. I'm trying to target all the ILS_Unit with a certain id and grab the MarketRent nodeValue. But there is a namespace, which I register, but I'm receiving a blank page.

**My PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load('http://mdoerrdev.com/xml/updates-mits.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('MITS', "http://mdoerrdev.com/xml/updates-mits.xml");

$unitPrice = $xpath->evaluate("//ILS_Unit[@FloorplanId='550584']/Unit/MITS:Information/MITS:MarketRent");
    foreach($unitPrice as $up)  {
        var_dump($up);
    };
?>
```

**The Input XML:**

Input XML is too big, so you can find it here: http://mdoerrdev.com/xml/updates-mits.xml

Comment: Could you be so kind the next time you ask a question posting the relevat information on this website into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register the namespace, make sure the URI matches the one in the XML, change:

```
 $xpath->registerNamespace('MITS', "http://mdoerrdev.com/xml/updates-mits.xml");
```

to

```
 $xpath->registerNamespace('MITS', "http://www.mitsproject.org/namespace");
```

Comment: I made this change. Still getting a blank document. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Oh I had a type, this is what I get now, http://mdoerrdev.com/xml/testing2.php . How do I now go from that to target just the MarketRent ?

Comment: You are executing XPath `//ILS_Unit[@FloorplanId='550584']/Unit/Information/MarketRent`. This will find all MarketRent elements with the FloorplanId given in de XPath. The XML found on pastie.org does not contain this FloorplanId. But I think it is found more than once

Comment: Maybe you are searching for this XPath: `//Property/Floorplan[@Id='550578']/MarketRent`